# MacOS different NodeJS in local, how to find and remove them all?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, uninstallation

I'm having issue to switch my NodeJS version on my Mac. I'm currently having v12 NodeJS and want to downgrade to v11, even though I tried removing node file and folder in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, `/usr/local/bin`, and `/usr/local/share`, `node -v` still works fine and print `v12.18.3`

These are the versions:

```sh
# Below command print: v12.18.3
node -v
# Try switching using `n` tool
n 11.15.0
# No errors printed out, then verify
node -v
# still prints v12.18.3
```

I added this to my `NODE_PATH` but it didn't work too:

```sh
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/bin
```

I have tried restarting the shell terminal, and still the same.

How can I remove the Node entirely? I don't mind reinstall it as long as it works.

If I run `npm config list`:

```sh
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.6 node/v12.18.3 darwin x64"

; userconfig /Users/jeemok/.npmrc
prefix = "/usr/local"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "/usr/local"

; node bin location = /usr/local/Cellar/node@12/12.18.3/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/jeemok/tincode/admin-panel
; HOME = /Users/jeemok
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

is it something to do with the `node bin location`? How can I change it to the global NodeJS? can I simply delete the `/usr/local/Cellar/node@12/` folder?

Note: I've already tried:

- https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using homebrew, I'd recommend using it to install [`nodenv`](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv) for switching.

```
$ brew install nodenv
$ nodenv install 11.15.0
```

When you open a new shell `node` will be a shim that selects a version of node.

`nodenv local` will set the version for the directory (project). `shell` for this session. `global` as the default for the user.

```
$ nodenv shell 11.15.0
$ node --version
v11.15.0
```

You can still select the default system version of node required:

```
$ nodenv versions
  system
  8.17.0
  10.22.0
  11.15.0
  12.18.3
  14.7.0
```

Comment: No worries =) fyi a lot of languages have a clone of rbenv, e.g. pyenv, plenv, jenv

Comment: thanks for sharing the info! I can't believe installation / uninstallation of NodeJS can be such a headache!